# How to release Agent capacity for real-time Work Item w/o the agent having to close the tab

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel

E.g., release the capacity on the Chat end while the tab stays active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add an Aura component to the Utility bar (to ensure it oversees all chats and tabs) that uses `omniToolkitApi` method to release capacity after receiving the lightning:conversationChatEnded event.

HTML:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" access="global">
<lightning:omniToolkitAPI aura:id="omniToolkit" />
<aura:handler
  event="lightning:conversationChatEnded"
  action="{!c.onChatEnded}"
/>
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
  onChatEnded: function (cmp, evt) {
  const recordId = evt.getParam("recordId");
  const omniAPI = cmp.find("omniToolkit");
  omniAPI
    .getAgentWorks()
    .then(function (result) {
      const works = JSON.parse(result.works);
      for (const work of works) {
        if (work.workItemId === recordId) {
          omniAPI
            .closeAgentWork({ workId: work.workId })
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });    
  }
});
```